# Data of previous quarters based on sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration, date-arithmetic

I have below requirement.

Suppose I run the query on `15-APR-2019` then I should get the data of `4th quarter 2018(01-OCT-18 to 31-DEC-18)` . If I run the query on `15-MAY-2019` I should get data of `1st quarter of 2019(01-JAN-2019 to 31-MAR-2019)`.

Means if there is 30 days difference on quarter end data and current date then I should get data of previous quarter. but if there is less than 30 days difference i should get data of previous to previous quarter.

means if

```
I run on 15-APR-2019 data should be of (01-OCT-2018 to 31-DEC-2018)
I run on 01-APR-2019 data should be of (01-OCT-2018 to 31-DEC-2018)
I run on 01-MAY-2019 data should be of (01-JAN-2019 to 31-MAR-2019)
I run on 01-JUN-2019 data should be of (01-JAN-2019 to 31-MAR-2019)
```

How can I put this criteria in where clause. we have to calculate data based on `sysdate` and it has to be compared by date stored in database.

Comment: This is a simple question you just have to use the CASE statement.  Where are you running into an issue?  Remember the only part that changes here is the year.

Comment: how can i calculate 30 days then put the "Between logic in output" and compare it with = condition. Could you please help me with syntax

Comment: Do you really mean 30 days, or do you mean a month?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select trunc(sysdate - 30, 'Q') - interval '3' month
```

If you want the complete data:

```
where date >= trunc(sysdate - 30, 'Q') - interval '3' month and
      date < trunc(sysdate - 30, 'Q')
```

Comment: Hi Gordon , I am actually able to calculate the date and quarter based on your previous answers some days back.....Actually I am not able to fit it on where clause using case.

Answer (score 2):

```
with s as
(select date '2019-04-15' dt from dual union all
 select date '2019-04-01' dt from dual union all
 select date '2019-05-01' dt from dual union all
 select date '2019-06-01' dt from dual
)
select dt, d1, add_months(d1, 3) - 1 d2
from
   (select dt, add_months(trunc(dt, 'q'), case when dt - trunc(dt, 'q') < 30 then -6 else -3 end) d1
    from s
   );

DT                  D1                  D2                 
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2019-04-15 00:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00 2018-12-31 00:00:00
2019-04-01 00:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00 2018-12-31 00:00:00
2019-05-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31 00:00:00
2019-06-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-03-31 00:00:00
```